# How do you get Python to ask the user for an input 'x' amount of times?

Tags: python

I am trying to get Python to ask the user the same question 'x' amount of times depending on what the user determines 'x' to be. So I am trying to achieve for Python to ask the user 'how many numbers would you like to find the average for'.

I thought the first line could be

```
x = eval(input('How many numbers would you like to find the average for?: '))
```

and then for Python to ask something like 'Enter a number' an x amount of times.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `eval`. Convert the input to `int`

```
x = int(input('How many numbers would you like to find the average for?: '))
```

Then use that to loop

```
values = []
for i in range(x):
    values.append(int(input('Please enter a value')))
```

Answer (score 1):

At the start you can create a empty "numbers" list:

```
numbers = []
```

And I'd recommend for you to use `int()` instead of `eval()`.

```
x = int(input('How many numbers would you like to find the average for? '))
```

Then you can start a `for()` loop and put an input inside it:

```
for i in range(x):
    n = int(input('Number ' + str(i+1) + ': '))
```

And then still in the loop use `append()` to put the numbers in the list:

```
for i in range(x):
    n = int(input('Number ' + str(i+1) + ': '))
    numbers.append(n)
```

Then for the calculation at the end you can use `sum()` to get the sum of all the numbers in the list, and then divide it by the length (using `len()`) of the list:

```
final = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
```

But if you want to round the final number, use `round()`:

```
final = round(sum(numbers) / len(numbers))
```

And this is the final code:

```
numbers = []

x = int(input('How many numbers would you like to find the average for? '))

for i in range(x):
    n = int(input('Number ' + str(i+1) + ': '))
    numbers.append(n)

final = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
finalRounded = round(final)
```

Then you would obviously print it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = eval(input('How many numbers would you like to find the average for?: '))
for count in range (x):
    amount = input (f"Enter number{count+1}:\n")
```

This will help you to ask the user for repeated inputs depending on the amount they entered, and also when the program asks the user for input every time it will go as follows:

```
Enter number 1
Enter number 2
```

and so on until the program is completed and you can change `Enter Number` to anything you like.

Comment: This is for Python 3.  For Python 2 `x = input('How many numbers would you like to find the average for?: ')`

Answer (score -2):

use a forLoop statement...

read x, then

for y in range(0, x):
    user input goes here (y is an int that will show how many times youve gone into the for statement)

and thats mainly it